# Storm and spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-storm

I want to check and see if it is a good idea to invoke Spark code from a storm bolt. We have a stream based system in Storm. So per message we would like to do so ML and we are thinking of using Spark for that. So wanted to check if it is a good idea to do so. Any run time issues we might encounter ?

Thanks
ap

Comment: Have you considered using spark streaming instead?

Comment: The storm system is built. So we have no plans to rewrite to Spark-streaming now.

Answer (score 0):

if you already have a system in place with Storm, then why do you want to use Spark?

IMHO both Spark and storm are different beast, you may want to run them in parallel for same or different use cases but do not tightly integrate each other.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean ML per message? ML on a single message doesn't make much sense. Do you mean a ML on a stream? Sure you can do it with Spark, but then you need to either use Spark Streaming (and you have two streaming architectures...) or save the data somewhere and do batch ML with Spark.

Why not use [trident-ml](https://github.com/pmerienne/trident-ml) instead?